# Is it possible to use hidden methods by creating a copy of an AOSP API code?

Tags: android

I was wondering if it's possible to use hidden methods of an open-source API by creating a copy of the API under a new name without the member method marked as hidden?

If it can't be done (because people would have already done that instead of using reflection), what are the reasons for it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I'm asking in the context of APIs which are a part of the Android framework (AOSP)

Comment: That's the specific objective of forking a repository. If you have it on GitHub, fork it under your account, clone the repository inside your Android src, and edit any code as you wish.

Comment: @ArthurAttout I meant to ask specifically for Android's own APIs - does it work for them too?

Comment: **If** the API is open source yes. What API exactly ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout the Wifi P2p API - some methods like deleting previous configuration or changing device name require hidden methods if you want to perform those actions programmatically. I want to be able to do that without the user having to navigate to the corresponding Settings option and do it manually everytime.